# Логарифм в С++ по основанию

Tags: c++, математика

есть две переменные: x и y. нужно вычислить логарифм от числа x по основанию y. как это реализовать?
стандартная функция log считает только натуральные логарифмы и логарифмы по основанию 10

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath

Answer (score 8):

Немного школьной математики... Свойства логарифмов ниже. Внимательно смотрите на десятое свойство. Пояснять подробнее? :)

Например, логарифм по основанию 5 числа x вычисляется как

```
log(x)/log(5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы как  профессиональный педагог объяснили:))

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вот чего не было в жизни, того не было. Даже репетиторством не получалось заниматься - только решение всяких контрольных, это пожалуйста :) Правда, сейчас с малым приходится заниматься, выпускной класс - но и тут это получается не слишком хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная функция `std::log` как раз десятичные логарифмы не считает, а считает натуральные логарифмы. Ещё есть `std::log10`, `std::log2`, `std::log1p`. Для остальных считайте, используя следующее свойство, которое следует из определения функции логарифма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дока - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath.